# How to access String within an ArrayList within an ArrayList within a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I have this ArrayList full of Strings

```
ArrayList<String> colours = new ArrayList<>();
    colours.add("Red");
    colours.add("Blue");
```

And that ArrayList is stored in another ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> container = new ArrayList<>();
    container.add(colors);
```

And that ArrayList is stored in a HashMap

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, container);
```

How do I access "red"? I tried

```
System.out.println(map.get(1).get(0).get(0));
```

But it gave a

```
Error: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method get(int)
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use raw types like `ArrayList<ArrayList>` but use fully "cooked" types such as `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (or even better, `List<List<String>>`).

Likewise, instead of `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList>`, use `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>` (or even better, `Map<Integer, List<List<String>>>`).

If you make these changes, your `map.get(1).get(0).get(0)` expression will compile correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this:

```
  HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> map = new HashMap<>();
```

With:

```
  HashMap<Integer, List<ArrayList<String>>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<List<String>>>();
```

In this case you can do this:

```
  System.out.println(map.get(1).get(0).get(0));
```

because the `1st` `get(1)` for the `map`, the `2nd` `get(0)` for the 1st `List` and the `3th` get(0) for the 2nd `List`.